# How to configure angular-strap to work with AngularAMD?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-strap, angular-amd

I'm building an application with Angularjs, using AngularAMD to dynamically load modules.

I need now to use Angular-strap(http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) in this project, but I don't know how to declare-it in my main.js file.

This is my main.js file:

```
require.config({
   baseUrl: "js/app/",
   paths: {
      'angular': '../angular/angular',
      'angular-route': '../angular/angular-route',
      'angular-animate': '../angular/angular-animate',
      'angularAMD': '../angularAMD/angularAMD',

      'srvItinerarioEscolhido': 'servicos/itinerarioEscolhido',
      'srvComunicacaoWebApi': 'servicos/comunicacaoWebApi',
      'srvCacheDados': 'servicos/cacheDados',
      'dirTabsPesquisas': 'diretivas/pesquisas/dirTabsPesquisas'
   },

   shim: {
      'angularAMD': ['angular'],
      'angular-route': ['angular'],
      'angular-animate': ['angular']
   },


   deps: ['app']
});
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried something as simple as: 'angular-strap': "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.1.3/angular-strap"?

Comment: @marcoseu, You are right, it is actually pretty simple. It worked fine, thanks.